# C# class variables in propertygrid? [non setter/getters]

Tags: c#, class, variables, propertygrid

I have looked pretty much everywhere but cannot seem to find an awnser to this.
I'm building a level editor for a game where I want to select objects and show their variables in a propertygrid to edit them during runtime.

Here's an example class:

```
public class InteractiveObject
{
    public Vector2 location = Vector2.Zero;
    public  float _width = 0;
    public  float _height = 0;


    virtual public float width
    {
        get
        {
            return _width;
        }
        set { _width = value; }
    }

    virtual public float height
    {
        get
        {
            return _height;
        }
        set { _height = value; }
    }

}
```

The propertygrid is only showing width and height right now.
I'm binding the class to the propertygrid like this:

```
InteractiveObject obj = new InteractiveObject();
propertyGrid.SelectedObject = obj;
```

Any idea's on how to show the variables and reflect the changes made in the propertrygrid back to the object?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using WPF for your GUI?

Comment: PropertyGrid is meant to show only the public properties. It doesnt not display class fields. Can't you just make properties for what you would like to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make these members (location, width, height) properties instead, and you should also make them virtual like the other properties.  This class looks like it should be a base class that other things will inherit from, and you're limiting their ability to be customized by sticking those items in as public members rather than public virtual properties.

When it's a virtual property, two things happen:

1. all access must come in through the get/set because the class member is not public
2. that access can be customized by subclasses

Even if you do it for no other reason than being able to put a debug break point or some diagnostic output in the property, it's probably worth it.

Also, it will instantly work with the property grid you mention (I suppose).

That said, reflection should be able to give you the public members, so in theory you could enhance this PropertyGrid (if it's your code) or write your own (if it's not) that would display both properties and public members.

Comment: I figured this was the solution. I didn't want to rewrite existing code, but guess I'll have to!

Comment: You could probably automate it by doing it in two steps: convert the members to properties but leave the inappropriate member-style names as the names of the properties, and then use a refactor operation to rename the properties to something more appropriate (ie, no underscore).